# Is there a way to use a watcher without a breakpoint in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

I could print out logs instead, but is there a way use a watcher outside of debug scope and just see every time a variable changes? It would save me the time of printing out the logs. As you know, in debug mode when there is no breakpoint, we can miss the state of what we are watching.  But if the watching could continue beyond the holding a breakpoint it would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

In short:  no, you can't really watch variables without a debugger to attach to the variables.  However, there may be a workaround.

You don't have to have the breakpoint actually suspend execution of your code.  You can set it so that it only logs an evaluated message to the console.

[image]

In this image I'm both logging an IntelliJ-specific message as well as evaluating an expression.  The result (it's just a loop from 0 to 9) is:

```
Breakpoint reached at SubsetSumAlgorithm.main(SubsetSumAlgorithm.java:8)
0
0
Breakpoint reached at SubsetSumAlgorithm.main(SubsetSumAlgorithm.java:8)
10
Breakpoint reached at SubsetSumAlgorithm.main(SubsetSumAlgorithm.java:8)
20
Breakpoint reached at SubsetSumAlgorithm.main(SubsetSumAlgorithm.java:8)
30
Breakpoint reached at SubsetSumAlgorithm.main(SubsetSumAlgorithm.java:8)
40
```

Comment: But in this case, the breakpoint still has to be triggered.  If execution does not land on the breakpoint then the "evaluated expression" does not run, right ? i was hoping i could watch a class field and print out values for it everytime it changes.  So i thought i could do: Log.v("MyTAG",tv.getText().toString()) in the "Log evaluated expression" field and have it ALWAYS watch for changes to tv object and when there is a change print out a message. That is really what i want, to simply watch/observe an object for changes and print out its content.